# Ingest .sql file and change sql statement parameter

Tags: go

Im working on a project that's meant to run a .Sql File that's a basic **CREATE TABLE** statement with some parameters.

The statement would be something like: **CREATE TABLE "name"** and when I run main, I can define the parameter for name.

First I need to read the file. One way to do this is with ioutil.ReadFile.
I don't think I can change the table name with a prepared statement, so I should have to do this manually.

For example with strings.ReplaceAll. And then call db.Exec with the result.

What do you think is the best way to complete this?

Comment: Have you considered using `text/template`? i.e. `CREATE TABLE "{{ .TableName }}"`?

Comment: why not? replace table name with "?" and do a prepared statement.
the table name insert into and args array and use "db.Exec(statement)"